# finding out if two vectors are perpendicular or parallel

Tags: calculus, vectors

I'm not sure if I quite get this.  For example,

(1, -1) and (-3, 3)

take the cross product, you will end up with
-3 + (-3)

This doesn't equal 0, so it's not perpendicular. So that leaves me with it being parallel. When are two vectors parallel?

Comment: You mean dot product, not cross product.

Comment: I think did you mean the "dot product".

Comment: Vectors $(a_1,a_2)$ and $(b_1,b_2)$ are parallel iff $\frac{a_1}{b_1}=\frac{a_2}{b_2}$

Comment: @user26486 Thanks! I really liked your comment. To clarify, is it because a vector is parallel if the ratio of one vector is equal to the ratio of another vector?

Comment: @user26486 would expressing it as $
\frac{a_1}{a_2}=\frac{b_1}{b_2}
$ also be appropriate?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can find the angle between the two vectors
$$\theta=\cos^{-1}\left(\frac{v_1 \cdot v_2}{\left|v_1\right|\left|v_2\right|}\right)$$
if $\theta=0$ or $180$ the two vectors are parallel

if $\theta=90$ the two vetors are perpendicular

Comment: In OP's problem, you get $$ \ \cos^{-1} \left( \frac{-6}{ \ \sqrt{2} \ \cdot \ 3 \sqrt{2}} \ \right) \ = \ \cos^{-1} (-1) \ = \ 180º \ \ ,  $$ so you may want to mention the case of anti-parallelism.  (Some folks _do_ use "parallel" to refer to _any_ vectors that are collinear.)

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Thanks

Comment: @colormegone: Please don't confuse (°, U+00B0: DEGREE SIGN) and (º, U+00BA: MASCULINE ORDINAL INDICATOR)!

Comment: Amir Naseri's answer is much much faster to use.

Answer (score 14):

Two vectors $v_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $v_2=(x_2,y_2)$ are parallel iff $x_1 \, y_2 = x_2 \, y_1$.

Comment: excellent for numerical stability (no need to worry about float comparison with square root)

Comment: Great answer. To elaborate the derivation: If you write the two vectors as columns of a 2x2 matrix then if they’re parallel the determinant will be zero giving exactly the equation above: $x_1 y_2 - x_2 y_1=0$

Answer (score 2):

Two vectors are parallel when they are scalar multiples of each other. In other words, if you can multiply one vector by a constant and end up with the other vector.

The rough reason for this is that multiplying by a scalar doesn't rotate the vector at all (it can stretch or flip the vector, but it doesn't change the direction).

Answer (score 1):

They are parallel if and only if they are different by a factor i.e. (1,3) and (-2,-6). 
The dot product will be 0 for perpendicular vectors i.e. they cross at exactly 90 degrees.

When you calculate the dot product and your answer is non-zero it just means the two vectors are not perpendicular.